# Find the minimum value on the fly while on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my html using `ng-repeat` the user click `addBox()` to append new input box to add new data:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
  <h5 class="over-title">Variant</h5>
    <a class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addBox()" ng-hide="btnVarianthide">Add Variant</a>
</div>
```

html:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in product.variant.variantdetail">
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="row.variant_dtl_name" required></td>
      <td>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">USD</span>
          <input type="number" ng-model="row.variant_dtl_price" required>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a ng-click="delVariantDetail($index)">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addVariantDetail()">Add Variant Detail</a>
```

These are my controller:

```
$scope.addBox = function() {
  $scope.variantArray = [];
  $scope.product.variant = {
    variantname: '',
    variantdetail:[{
      "variant_dtl_name": '',
      "variant_dtl_price": ''
    }]
  }
  $scope.btnVarianthide = true;
  $scope.boxShow = true;
};

$scope.addVariantDetail = function() {
  $scope.product.variant.variantdetail.push({
    "variant_dtl_name": '',
    "variant_dtl_price": ''
  });
};

$scope.delVariantDetail = function($index) {
  $scope.product.variant.variantdetail.splice($index,1);

  if($scope.product.variant.variantdetail.length == 0) {
    $scope.btnVarianthide = false;
    $scope.boxShow = false;
    delete $scope.product.variant;
  }
};
```

How can I get value `row.variant_dtl_price` from each newly added input box, so I can keep tracking the `minimum` value for discount calculation. Thanks!!

Comment: you can $watch this $scope.product.variant, and whenever it's updated you can recalculate this min value

Comment: Please create a plunkr to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Is seems that you never use `$scope.variantArray` in the controller? Can you provide the complete controller.js file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-change` directive to get notified when your array inside the `$scope` changes.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="row.variant_dtl_price" required ng-change="calcMin()">
```

Then add a function in your controller to recalculate the minimum every time detail price changes or a new detail gets added.

```
$scope.min = null;
$scope.calcMin = function(){
    var min = $scope.product.variant.variantdetail[0]["variant_dtl_price"];
    var allVariants = $scope.product.variant.variantdetail;
    for(var i=1;i<allVariants.length;i++){
        if(allVariants[i]["variant_dtl_price"]<min){
            min=allVariants[i]["variant_dtl_price"];
        }
    }
    $scope.min = min;
}
```

Here is the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/fd65B93X6s67DjB5lsa4?p=preview).

**Reference**: http://www.benlesh.com/2013/10/title.html